# How can I join two tables but only return rows that don't match?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables which look like this:

```
T1:  ID  |  Date  |  Hour  | Interval
T2:  ID  |  Date  |  Hour
```

I basically need to join these tables when their IDs, dates, and hours match.  However, I only want to return the results from table 1 that do **not** match up with the results in table 2.

I know this seems simple, but where I'm stuck is the fact that there are multiple rows in table 1 that match up with table 2 (there are multiple intervals for any given hour).  I need to return all of these intervals so long as they do not fall within the same hour period in table 2.

Example data:

```
T1:  1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  1
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  2
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  2  |  1
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  2  |  2

T2:  1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
```

My expected result set for this would be the last two rows from `T1`.  Can anyone point me on the right track?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.*
    FROM T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM T2
                         WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID 
                             AND T1.Date = T2.Date
                             AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour)
```

It could also be done with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.*
    FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                AND T1.Date = T2.Date
                AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour
    WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, both queries work well with MS Access.  To be honest, I never knew you could combine `SELECT` statements like that, +1.

Comment: Actually, one more response - I went with the first option, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.  Ingenious, I never knew you could do that, it worked beautifully.

Comment: Keep in mind that NOT EXISTS is not well-optimized by the Jet/ACE query processor and won't always use indexes on both sides of the comparison (the same is true of NOT IN, to a much greater degree). Thus, as the data set grows, you could see a major performance hit with the NOT EXISTS version. The JOIN version will always utilize all the available indexes.

Answer (score 27):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and filter out the lines that have non-`NULL` T2 columns:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    AND T1.Date = T2.Date AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour
    WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 and thank you for the answer, but I had to go with Joe's (he answered a few minutes faster).