# Expanding a query's result set (or using an intermediate table)?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613708/how-can-i-join-two-tables-but-only-return-rows-that-dont-match), there is an alternative that I would like to explore.  My table layout is as follows:

```
T1:  ID  |  Date  |  Hour  | Interval
```

The intervals span from `1` to `12` (the 5-minute interval in the hour), the hour goes from `1` to `24`, and the date/ID is arbitrary.  When I am pulling the data from an external source, there are some rows that have an interval of `0`.  When there is a `0` for the interval, this indicates that the entire hour is covered (i.e. all intervals from `1` to `12`).

Example data:

```
T1:  1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  1
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  4
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  0

     1  |  1/1/2011  |  2  |  2
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  2  |  5

     1  |  1/1/2011  |  3  |  0
```

Notice that there is an overlap of the intervals and a `0`-flagged interval.  Is there any way I can expand the `0` intervals into all 12 intervals for the hour?  So, I basically want to transform the example data into:

```
T1:  1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  1
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  2
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  3
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  4
     ...
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  11
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  |  12

     1  |  1/1/2011  |  2  |  2
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  2  |  5

     1  |  1/1/2011  |  3  |  1
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  3  |  2
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  3  |  3
     ...
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  3  |  11
     1  |  1/1/2011  |  3  |  12
```

Is something like this even possible using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table, "intervals", with 12 rows containing a single field, "iinterval", with values from 1 to 12.

```
iinterval
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
        7
        8
        9
       10
       11
       12
```

You can then do a cross join between the intervals table and those T1 rows where interval is zero.  (I renamed the T1 fields Date, Hour, and Interval because those are all reserved words.)

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.idate, T1.ihour, intervals.iinterval
FROM T1, intervals
WHERE T1.iinterval=0;
```

Since there is no JOIN condition specified, every T1 row (which has zero interval) will be joined with every intervals row.

```
ID  idate    ihour iinterval
 1  1/1/2011     1         1
 1  1/1/2011     1         2
 1  1/1/2011     1         3
 1  1/1/2011     1         4
 1  1/1/2011     1         5
 1  1/1/2011     1         6
 1  1/1/2011     1         7
 1  1/1/2011     1         8
 1  1/1/2011     1         9
 1  1/1/2011     1        10
 1  1/1/2011     1        11
 1  1/1/2011     1        12
```

If that gets what you wanted for the rows where interval equals zero, you can use it in a UNION query to add those rows to the T1 rows where the interval is **not** zero.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.idate, a.ihour, a.iinterval
FROM T1 AS a
WHERE a.iinterval<>0
UNION
SELECT T1.ID, T1.idate, T1.ihour, intervals.iinterval
FROM T1, intervals
WHERE T1.iinterval=0;
```

I hope this will point you to something useful, but doubt this is exactly what you ultimately want.  My reservation is because of this condition: "*Notice that there is an overlap of the intervals and a 0-flagged interval*".  I don't know what should happen in response to those overlaps.

Comment: Basically, I'm inner-joining this result set with another table, which only contains "valid" intervals (i.e. 1 through 12).  It should overlap existing ones (and get rid of the interval 0 rows), kind of how my result set looks (the hour 1 data in the end only contains intervals 1 through 12, no duplicates).  However, even if the method does leave me with duplicates, I'm sure I could create another query to filter out only the distinct rows...

Comment: UNION returns only distinct rows, so you may be covered on that point already (if I understood your comment correctly).  There is also UNION ALL, which operates faster than just UNION and would return all rows including duplicates.  But that's not what I was suggesting.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't know that `UNION` only returned distinct rows.  I shall accept this answer, but I'm curious, do you think there is a way to solve this problem without the use of an intermediate table (or is that outside the scope of the structured query language itself?)

Comment: Yes, I think so.  You don't have to save the results of the UNION query in a table.  Save it as a named query, then use that query and  your other table as the data sources in a new query.