# What type of join should i be using?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in sql server ...

- Table 1 contains 100,000 account names and account IDs
- Table 2 contains 10,000 account names and account IDs  that are already included in table 1

I need to show all the records that are in table 1, that don't also appear in table 2 (so that should give me 90,000 results.

I am completely stuck on how to show this, whether it be a join or a select in the where clause

thanks, and apologies I know lots of things like this are out in the ether

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I join two tables but only return rows that don't match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613708/how-can-i-join-two-tables-but-only-return-rows-that-dont-match). The accepted answer looks to be a good "general sql" solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a JOIN, I think you want EXCEPT.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Of course, that only works with the columns are the same, or if you can specify a common list of columns instead of *.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a <kbd>[LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178429%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)</kbd>.

Like so.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.AccountID = T2.AccountID
WHERE T2.AccountID IS NULL
```

**Explanation**: This will take all the rows from `Table1` and attempt to link them with all the rows in `Table2`. Where there is a match, the `Table2.AccountId` will have the matching `AccountID`. Where there isn't a match, the `Table2.AccountId` will be `NULL`.

Another way to do this is without a JOIN, is by using the `EXISTS` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact sql-server syntax, but in other databases you can either do

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.id not in (select id from table2)
```

alternatively the 'null join' method

```
select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing 2 SQL concepts:

A Join is used generally to join two tables together that are linked via some key: For example You may have a login table with usernames and passwords which has a USERID field. In another table you have the address information about the same user that also has the USERID field.  You would simply do `SELECT ... FROM passwords p join address a on p.userid = a.userid`. That will give you all user passwords and the associated user data with it.

In your case you dont need to combine, you just want to use NOT IN

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 WHERE somevalue not in (SELECT somevalue from table2)
```