# Making a List of Rows NOT in both tables

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following tables:

```
> table1
  id var1
1  1    5
2  2    5
3  3    5

> table2
  id var1
1  1    7
2  2    7
3  4    7
```

Based on the id column, I want to select rows that are not in shared by both tables, and identify which table they belong to. The final result would look like this:

```
  id var1 source
1  3    5 table1
2  4    7 table2
```

I think the final answer would require the use of an OUTER JOIN and a CASE WHEN statement, but I am not sure how to write the final answer. Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613708/how-can-i-join-two-tables-but-only-return-rows-that-dont-match https://superuser.com/questions/1328634/selecting-non-matching-records-from-full-outer-join either of these useful?

Comment: @CollinD: thank you so much for your reply! I will check these links out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `full outer join` here, then a combination of `coalesce` and **case expression** to identify which table is involved in the unmatched rows.

```
SELECT
      COALESCE(table1.id, table2.id) AS id
    , COALESCE(table1.var1, table2.var1) AS var1
    , CASE 
        WHEN table1.id IS NULL THEN 'table2'
        WHEN table2.id IS NULL THEN 'table1'
        END AS source
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.id IS NULL
    OR table2.id IS NULL
```